# vim cannot access variable in autocmd

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, formatting, variables, path

I am trying to configure `prettier-eslint` and `prettier-standard` as the js formatter with neoformat:

```
" neoformat should try formatprg where available
let g:neoformat_try_formatprg = 1
augroup vimrc
  " if eslint is found
  if HasEslint()
    "get path of prettier-eslint
    let g:prettier_eslint_path =  system('PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH && which prettier-eslint')
    echom g:prettier_eslint_path

    if s:has_eslintrc_path
      "get full path to eslintrc if eslintrc file exists
      let g:eslintrc_full_path = getcwd() + s:eslintrc_path
      echom g:eslintrc_full_path

      autocmd FileType javascript set formatprg = g:prettier_eslint_path --filePath g:eslintrc_full_path
    elseif s:has_eslintConfig
      let g:eslintConfig = system("jq < package.json '.eslintConfig'")
      echom g:eslintConfig
      autocmd FileType javascript set formatprg = g:prettier_eslint_path --eslintConfig g:eslintConfig
    endif
  else
    " just use prettier-standard
    autocmd FileType javascript set formatprg=prettier-standard
  endif
  autocmd BufWritePre *.js Neoformat
  " autocmd BufWritePre,TextChanged,InsertLeave *.js Neoformat
augroup end
```

When opening a `js` file, it gives me an error saying that it could not find `g:prettier_eslint_path`.

How can I configure vim to use the local version of `prettier-eslint` and pass the appropriate options to it. It seems to use the default settings if no options are provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would be nice to see the full error, on which line it complains. Nevertheless you have error in the script, the `set` command requires no spaces around `=`, or spaces at all after `=` sign. You should also use `setlocal`, since `set` works globally (it will set for all buffers). And whole auto-command expression should be enclosed in `execute` with concatenation with variables.

So, the `autocmd`s should look like this:

```
autocmd FileType javascript execute "setlocal formatprg=".g:prettier_eslint_path."\\ --filePath\\ ".g:eslintrc_full_path

autocmd FileType javascript execute "setlocal formatprg=".g:prettier_eslint_path."\\ --eslintConfig\\ ".g:eslintConfig
```

Also, because you're enclosing this in a `augroup`, would be usefull to add `au!` on a first line to clear this group

Comment: All my `autocmd` are enclosed within the same group called `vimrc`, I usually do `source %` on my `.vimrc` after changes and I do not want duplicates. Should I group autocmd by type such as `js-indent` instead.

Comment: I am getting the error `E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &` when I added the autocmd in place of the original `autocmd`. I have `set nocompatible` on top of my `.vimrc`, so it could be a line continuation issue [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696079/vimrc-causes-error-e10-should-be-followed-by-or)

Comment: It works for me with `\\ ` so shouldn't be that thing, or you broke those lines into multiple? Check the content of your variables that are used in those `autocmd`s. Maybe there is something needing escaping, like `space` or `backslash`. You get them from `system()` so there might be trailing `\n` at the end.

Comment: That may be the case, got same error when set variable with `system("echo $PATH")` - there was `\n` at the end. You need to call `substitute(<variable>, '[\n\t\r]\?', '', 'g')` on those variables and `fnameescape(<variable>)`

Comment: Thanks @grodzik, I got my vimrc to compile without errors now, I can see the correct values when I use `echom` to print the messages.